# How can I make my Unity cameraController move overhead or below instead of clamping to 90/-90 degrees?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am messing around with a cameraController in Unity and trying to make the camera "fly" around. To this end I need to camera to smoothly go over head and keep on the track its going without getting stuck at 90degrees / -90degrees.
There is a LOT of FPS cameras that clamp to this but how to a do the opposite and MAKE it go overhead or below?

```
void MouseLook(Vector2 mouseDelta)
    {

        // Collect Mouse Input
        shiftX += mouseDelta.x;
        shiftY += mouseDelta.y;
        //shiftZ += 

        float zeroX = 0.2f;
        float zeroY = 0.2f;
        float zeroZ = 0.2f;

        shiftX = Mathf.Clamp(shiftX, -1 - zeroX, 1 + zeroX);
        shiftY = Mathf.Clamp(shiftY, -1 - zeroY, 1 + zeroY);
        shiftZ = Mathf.Clamp(shiftZ, -1 - zeroZ, 1 + zeroZ);

        float deltaX = deltaValue(shiftX, zeroX);
        float deltaY = deltaValue(shiftY, zeroY);
        float deltaZ = deltaValue(shiftZ, zeroZ);

        // Rotate the camera based on input
        float rotationSpeed = 5f; // Adjust this value to control the rotation speed
        float vertRotationScale = 5;
        float horzRotationScale = 5;
        float rollRotationScale = 5;

        // Define the offset vector relative to the camera's current rotation
        Vector3 offset = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles) * new Vector3(deltaX, deltaY, 10);

        // Set the position of the lookAtTarget relative to the camera's current position and rotation
        lookAtTarget.transform.position = transform.position + offset;

        // Calculate the target rotation based on the lookAtTarget position
        Vector3 targetDirection = lookAtTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection, Vector3.up);

        // Smoothly rotate the transform to the target rotation
        float rotationStep = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationStep);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you specify `Vector3.up` as the up direction, when you look up or down (`targetDirection` parallels to `Vector3.up`), the method stucks.

```
Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection, Vector3.up);
```

If the camera doesn't shake too much, you can simply use its up vector:

```
Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection, transform.up);
```

You can also somehow calculate it:

```
Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection, Vector3.Cross(targetDirection, transform.right));
```

Comment: Thanks this was the very precise change i needed. transform.up